# Multiple Search in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have a table with columns Firstname,middlename and lastname , implemented custom 'text filter' to search. How can  I implement multiple search that allows user to enter a word and it should fetch among all the rows with that word matching at least one of the 3 columns.

I tried to implement by creating a new table ,check measure and measure , by union of all the columns.And this procedure is taking more space as a new table is created for it.

Is there any other way to do multiple search other than the above mentioned one so it does not increase the size of the file.

Comment: Great article that might help: [Creating a slicer that filters multiple columns(...)](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/creating-a-slicer-that-filters-multiple-columns-in-power-bi/)

Comment: Ya it worked but the slicer will take more memory as it has many records, any other better way.